# access to spark, in a mesos cluster setup by dcos

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, mesos, mesosphere

I'm trying DCOS to setup a spark/mesos cluster. 
I deployed the mesos cluster on AWS, and everything went smoothly, except that the cluster is put in a dedicated VPC almost inaccessible from anywhere.

The rest of my apps are in another VPC (default one), how am I supposed to access the services hosted on from there ?
I tried to setup a VPC peering, with routes, and new rules in security groups, but I'm stuck, and I don't feel I'm in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Did you setup a dcos cluster via [the Mesosphere site](https://mesosphere.com/amazon/)? In that case I would actually recommend to use the chat button on the lower left of the DCOS UI.

Otherwise -if I understand your problem correctly- you should have a look at [this tutorial](https://docs.mesosphere.com/tutorials/publicapp/) in order to make applications available to the public. A general overview of the security model can be found [here](https://docs.mesosphere.com/getting-started/dcosarchitecture/#security).

So basically there are two options:

- Start your tasks on public nodes (by setting acceptedResourceRoles": ["slave_public"])
- Add an Edge Router making the tasks running on private slaves available to the outside.

For more details check [the above link](https://docs.mesosphere.com/tutorials/publicapp/).